# Expression type float list list list but was expected of type float list list, but the signatures are correct? (matrix addition)

Tags: matrix, ocaml, recurrent-neural-network

I am getting an error that says exactly this:

```
Error: This expression has type float list list list 
but an expression was expected of type float list list
Type float list is not compatible with type float
```

The error was in a function that's supposed to add list list matrices called `hopTrain`:

```
let rec hopTrain = function (allStates) -> 
 if((allStates == []))
  then[]
 else if((List.tl allStates == []))
  then hopTrainAstate(List.hd allStates) (* if only one state then output that state *)
  else hopTrain3(hopTrainAllStates(allStates), hopTrainAllStates(allStates));;
```

The error was in the last else calling of `hopTrain3` even though it's signature looks like this:

```
val hopTrain3 :
float list list list * float list list list -> float list list list = <fun>
```

I'll post the other functions too:

```
let rec multiplyAll = function (head, alist) ->
 if((alist == []))
    then []
 else if((head == List.hd alist))
    then 0.0::multiplyAll(head, List.tl alist)
    else (head *. List.hd alist)::multiplyAll(head, List.tl alist);;

let rec hopTrainAstate2 = function (astate, bstate) ->
 if((astate == []))
    then []
    else multiplyAll(List.hd astate, bstate)::hopTrainAstate2(List.tl astate, bstate);;

(* Returns weight matrix for only one stored state, used as a 'warmup' for the next function *)
let rec hopTrainAstate = function (astate) ->
 hopTrainAstate2(astate, astate);;

let rec hopTrainAllStates = function (allStates) ->
 if((allStates == []))
    then []
    else hopTrainAstate(List.hd allStates)::hopTrainAllStates(List.tl allStates);;
(* THIS ONE WORKS *)
let rec hopTrain3 = function (allStates, allStates2) ->
 if((allStates == []) || allStates2 == [])
    then []
    else addLists2(List.hd allStates, List.hd allStates2)::hopTrain3(List.tl allStates, List.tl allStates2);;

let rec addLists = function (alist, blist) ->
 if((alist == []) && (blist == []))
    then []
    else List.hd alist +. List.hd blist::addLists(List.tl alist, List.tl blist);;

let rec addLists2 = function (alist, blist) ->
 if((alist = blist))
    then alist
 else if((alist == []) || (blist == []))
    then []
    else addLists(List.hd alist, List.hd blist)::addLists2(List.tl alist, List.tl blist);;
```

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? You're missing at least the function `hopTrainAsState`.

Comment: Also, though this is not the source of your problem, you really don't want to use the `==` operator. It works for empty lists, but you risk failing in weird ways when you try to compare non-empty lists. The simple `=` operator does the trick perfectly.

Comment: @glennsl Sorry! I'll add hopTrainAState in the post.

Comment: @PatJ That didn't fix my problem here but I'm sure it'll help me later down the line so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should really learn how to use pattern matching, and use it instead of `List.hd` and `List.tl` operators. It is also a bad idea to pass tuples to functions, instead of passing multiple arguments.

For example, the `addLists` function, which you define as

```
let rec addLists = function (alist, blist) ->
  if((alist == []) && (blist == []))
  then []
  else List.hd alist +. List.hd blist::addLists(List.tl alist, List.tl blist)
```

while the idiomatic OCaml code will look like

```
let rec add_lists xs ys = match xs,ys with
  | [],[] -> []
  | x::xs, y::ys -> x +. y :: add_lists xs ys
  | _,[] | [],_ -> invalid_arg "add_listss: lists are of different lengths"
```

Notice also, how the error matching automatically shows you that your lists could have different lengths.

Now, the `hopTrain` function. It is a usual mistake in OCaml programming, to interpret an error message very local and jump to conclusions :) If you will look more carefully, the error message was corresponding to the whole 
`opTrain3(hopTrainAllStates(allStates), hopTrainAllStates(allStates))` expression (and it was highlighted for you by OCaml).

So it basically says, this expression is ok, and it has type `float list list list`, i.e., a 3d list. But I need the `float list list` here, so your cube doesn't fit into my square.

The next question that you should ask yourself is why the compiler expects a square here? The answer is simple -- it is your `then` branch, which is an expression `hopTrainAstate(List.hd allStates)` which has type `float list list`. 
So you have an expression

```
if cond then it_is_square else it_is_cube
```

But both sides of the `if` expression should have the same type - as the type of an expression can not depend on some condition - it is a static property of a value.

I don't really know what your function should compute if there is only one state, but the following code at least typechecks:

```
let rec hopTrain = function (allStates) ->
  if((allStates == []))
  then[]
  else if((List.tl allStates == []))
  then [hopTrainAstate(List.hd allStates)] (* if only one state then output that state *)
  else hopTrain3(hopTrainAllStates(allStates), hopTrainAllStates(allStates));;
```

Also, maybe it is the rules of the play of your assignment so that you have to use this `'a list list list` to structure your data. But in the real world, it is assumed a very bad practice. You should always use specific data types to denote objects in your domain, e.g., something like this

```
type row = {row : float list}
type matrix = { rows : row list}
type weights = { weights : matrix}
```

This rigid typing will make your code easier to understand and harder to break. Remember the following OCaml bumper stick saying:

> When in doubt, use more types!